# Get unique IDs with date 1 or date 2. For IDs with both date, obtain row with most recent of the 2 dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, spreadsheet, excel-filter

I have been trying to retrieve the row in the following sheet (sheet1) where the dates are matching dates in sheet2 without duplicating the IDs in Sheet1 (Column B)

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

In other words, I want to check if EITHER dates in Sheet2 exists in Sheet1 for an ID in Column B and obtain the row in Sheet1 with the more recent date of the two selected dates in sheet2. Here is an example of the output I want:

**Example Output**

[image]

So far, I am getting duplicates of IDs: one with each of the two dates.

(It has to be a formula since this will be dynamic where a different date would be selected in sheet 2)

Here is my formula currently:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$11, LARGE(IF(((Sheet1!$C$2:$C$11=Sheet2!$C$2)+(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$11=Sheet2!$C$3)>0),
MATCH(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11), ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11)), “”), ROW(Sheet1!C1)), COLUMN(Sheet1!A1)),
“”)
```

Here is the output I am getting. Notice the duplicated IDs in red. I only want the rows with more recent dates in green.

[image]

I’m not opposed to helper columns but The data in sheet1 is also subject to change and I don’t want my output to have any gaps.

I’m very new to this so any suggestions are appreciated!
Please! I have been at this for days now.

Here is the image of the excel sheets:

[image]

Comment: I think you have made the post little complicated ,,, [edit] the post & add some screen shots all about the expected results. Also [following link.](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)  to improve the post.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? Can you use functions like filter, let and unique?

Comment: Sorry I’m new to this, not sure why the screenshots are showing up as links. But I edited and added more photos. 
Yes I tried filter and unique but I can only get a unique id not the date with it. I tried to do a v lookup but I can’t get the correct date column with the id

Comment: So when I did unique(filter(sheet1$b$2:$b$11,((sheet1$c$2:$c$11=sheet2!$c$2)+(sheet1$c$2:$c$11=sheet2!$c$3))) it’s still giving me duplicates. And idk how to incorporate MAX since it would just pick the 6/4/22 date

Comment: What happens if only one of the date exists? What should the output be?

Answer (score 1):

My proposal:

```
=LET(s, SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$11, (Sheet1!$C$2:$C$11=Sheet2!$C$2)+(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$11=Sheet2!$C$3)),3,-1), 
w, CHOOSECOLS(s,2), SORT(UNIQUE(CHOOSEROWS(s, MATCH(w,w,0))),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have latest version of Excel, you can use this formula:
`=LET(d_1,MIN(F2:F3),d_2,MAX(F2:F3),ID_2,FILTER(B2:B11,C2:C11=d_2),ID_1,FILTER(B2:B11,(C2:C11=d_1)*(IFERROR(MATCH(B2:B11,ID_2,0)=0,TRUE))),t_1,FILTER(A2:C11,(IFERROR(MATCH(B2:B11,ID_1,0),FALSE))*(C2:C11=d_1)),t_2,FILTER(A2:C11,C2:C11=d_2),VSTACK(t_1,t_2))`

`=LET(`

- `d_1,MIN(F2:F3),` - earlier date
- `d_2,MAX(F2:F3),` - later date
- `ID_2,FILTER(B2:B11,C2:C11=d_2),` - IDs appearing with later date
- `ID_1,FILTER(B2:B11,(C2:C11=d_1)*(IFERROR(MATCH(B2:B11,ID_2,0)=0,TRUE))),` - IDs appearing with earlier date only
- `t_1,FILTER(A2:C11,(IFERROR(MATCH(B2:B11,ID_1,0),FALSE))*(C2:C11=d_1)),` - records for ID_1
- `t_2,FILTER(A2:C11,C2:C11=d_2),` - records for ID_2
- `VSTACK(t_1,t_2)` - merged results

`)`

[image]